# Find Data in a request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found a code in a article as below.
In this code, what does jsonrequest[define.AddStudent]) mean? Does the [define.AddStudent] resembles 'contains of' string in the variable jsonrequest? Kindly help what does line B mean?

```
var jsonrequest = JSON.parse(data); //Line A

if(jsonrequest[define.AddStudent]) { // Line B
    //where define.AddStudent="add student";
    console.log("Request for " + define.AddStudent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **jsonrequest** variable is a JavaScript object.

The **define** variable is also a JavaScript object.  **AddStudent** is a property / method of the define object.  Let us assume that it is a string property containing "add student", as the comment tells us.

Then, the meaning of line B is:  "If the property named **"add student"** of the **jsonrequest** object is defined."